# Convert milliseconds to individual format in C# NPOI

Tags: c#, formatting, export-to-excel, npoi

I use NPOI .NET third party library to export datas to *.xlsx file.
I have got a time value which represented in milliseconds.
For example, 2 minutes 12 seconds 3 milliseconds represented as 132003 milliseconds.
I would like to display "132003" as "02m 12.003s" in Excel.
So if i click a cell in excel which contains this value, i would like to see "02m 12.003s" in the cell, and "132003" in the formula editor.

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code below:

```
var t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(521516);
var formatted = String.Format("{0:D2}m:{1:D2}s:{2:D3}ms", t.Minutes, t.Seconds, t.Milliseconds);
System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine(formatted);
```

This will output:

> 08m:41s:516ms

You can use that code to retrive the formatted text and then add it to **excel**.

Comment: I would like set 132003 to cell. After that i would like to apply individual formatstyle to this cell. I would not like to store this formatted string value of this 132003 value.